# Returned aggregated result as an array : mongodb

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have this function in my db.js wrapper library for mongodb:

```
findAllSorted: function(name, sortBy, callback) {
  db.createCollection(name, function(err, collection) {
    collection.aggregate([{$sort: sortBy}], function(err, result) {
      console.log(result); // I want to return result as an array.
    });
  });
},
```

I would like to return `result` as an array via a callback. How would I do this? For instance I invoke this function with `db.findAllSorted('quotes', {unitprice: -1}, callback);` which as I understand should return my list of stock quotes in highest-to-lowest unitprice descending order.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

collection.aggregate(query, callback) returns the result as an array. All you need to do in the function above is call the callback. Assuming you want to let the function caller handle the error too:

```
findAllSorted: function(name, sortBy, callback) {
    db.createCollection(name, function(err, collection) {
        collection.aggregate([{$sort: sortBy}], function(err, result) {
            callback(err, result);
        });
    });
},
```

Comment: Worked as expected. Thanks again.